# Fatal error: Class 'LaravelLocalization' not found after composer install in production

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

It's been 3 days since I'm working on translating my site, so I installed [LaravelLocalization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/):

I did everything working in local, then I pushed it in production and executed:

```
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
composer dump-autoload -o
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
```

Now, all the "php artisan commands fail with:"

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
 Fatal error: Class 'LaravelLocalization' not found
```

In this case, in the composer install script, it fails in:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

I tried to run:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

But without any results...

Any ideas??? This is not the first time I get this kind of stuff, but I may say that this it's a pain in the ass :(

EDIT:

In my routes.php,

I deleted this line:

Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect']],

around all my routes, and now composer install works.

But it doesn't solve my issue, because as soon as I put it back, I still get the same error :(

Comment: Did you update your `compose.json` file in prod?

Comment: yep, composer.json is part of my git rep

Comment: Can you confirm that `"mcamara/laravel-localization"` is in the production `composer.json`

Comment: Is `composer.lock` part of your repo?

Comment: "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^1.1" double checked

Comment: composer.lock is also in my git rep

Comment: I also checked I have it installed in vendor folder in production

Comment: check edited question, clue in routes prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it removing the line:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect']],
```

in my file routes.php

run again

```
composer install
```

and finally

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

What I don't know is why it happened, and if there is a way to prevent it...

Answer (score 1):

as what the error says, it means that the composer can't locate your package. so be sure to 
check your config/app.php file 
be sure to put the package in providers and aliases arrays, respectively.

Comment: try to reinstall the package. first clear all the changes you made in app.php and dump autoload and clear cache in your composer. after that try to install the package.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a known issue for a while, but has actually finally been resolved recently. You can read about the [issue here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9678).

Basically, running `php artisan` loads the entire framework, including the cached files. Since the cached files don't have your service provider, you get the error. This includes running `php artisan clear-compiled`. So, it is using the cached files in the command that is used to delete the cached files.

This issue has finally been resolved as of `laravel/framework:v5.2.25` and `laravel/laravel:v5.2.27`, and backported to `laravel/framework:v5.1.33` and `laravel/laravel:v5.1.33`.

This fix includes a change to the Laravel application (`laravel/laravel`), in addition to the Laravel Framework (`laravel/framework`). To implement, you will need to:

1) Update the `scripts` section of your `composer.json` file to match that in the [`laravel/laravel` package](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.29/composer.json). Specifically:

- remove the `pre-update-cmd` section
- in the `post-install-cmd` section, replace `"php artisan clear-compiled"` with `"Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall"`
- in the `post-update-cmd` section, replace `"php artisan clear-compiled"` with `"Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"`

2) Once you have updated your `composer.json`, run a `composer update`. If you only want to update the framework, you can run `composer update laravel/framework`.